# Is that possible Relative Layout with Spinner under Scroll View?

Tags: android

i am using Scroll View , under which i have taken Relative Layout with Spinner , But it is not working . Why ? while if i used UI element like Edit Text/Text View, than it is OK.   I tried below code ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/itr1_personalInfo_gender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What is the error or issue you got ???

Comment: what you want to achieve from above code?

Answer (score 0):

I misunterstood the post so i edited it 
Edit : Thats possible to be used
Please just sent the logcat you get error